# Do the measurements of the Ark have any important significance?

Tags: exodus, daniel, numerology, ark-of-the-covenant

Exodus 25:10 says:

> <sup>10</sup> “Have them make an ark[b] of acacia wood—two and a half cubits long, a cubit and a half wide, and a cubit and a half high.

**My question is**:

Given that

- 2.5 + 1.5 + 1.5 = 5.5 cubits, which is half the measure of 5, 3 and 3 (which are equal to 11 when added), and
- 11 being a Triangular number that is equal to 66, and the sum of the Ark that is 66 also,

what is the important significance of 66 other than its being found in the middle of 62 and 70 in Daniel 9?

The only explanation I can come up with is that the five book of Moses, which has 187 chapters in total, are the knowledge and the wisdom of the hand of G-D and the Holy fire or the burning bush, and any women can't approach the Holy Ark or be in the temple where the Ark is present other than a person who is selected by the Creator.

Hebrew alphabets have 22 letters, which is 11×2 and the triangular number is 23 × 11 = 253.  23 × 11 - 6 × 11 = 187.

5     9     13

17    21    25

29    33    37

41    45    49

53    57    61

17+45=62   21+45=66    25+45=70

41+21=62   45+21=66    49+21=70

62+66+70=198      66+66+66=198 62+70=132

66÷11=6    66÷11=6     66÷11=6

132÷2=66        11+6=17  11+6=17  11+6=17

17+41=58   21+45=66    25+49=74

5+53=58     9+57=66    13+61=74

58+66+74=198  58+74=132  132÷2=66

66+66+66=198

66÷11=6  66÷11=6  66÷11=6

11+6=17  11+6=17  11+6=17

1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11=6×11

An angel goes to a woman who will be pregnant and that her son will have an 11'th hour ministry and he saw saw dreams that came to pass.

Comment: This needs a more detailed explanation if anyone is going to be able to follow it.  Yes, 5.5 is half the sum of 5, 3, and 3, but where did the 5, 3, and 3 come from? — "*11 being a triangular number*", by what definition? In math, 10 is triangular, not 11. — "*the important significance of 66 other than being found in the middle of 62 and 70 in the book of Daniel chapter nine*", but isn't 66 in the middle of 62 and 70 in *every* chapter of *every* book? — Far too many things are being thrown in, but there is nothing here to indicate why anyone should think they have any special significance.

Comment: I would suggest rewriting this as if you are talking to someone that has no idea what you are talking about.  Fill in *all* the details that you are taking for granted and assuming that other people already know or can easily figure out.

Comment: The triangular number for 11 is 66 and 11+6=17.in wikipedia if you look out for the number of the beast it is written 666 wich is the triangular number of 36,they said.king Solomon's wealth was 666 talents  of gold every year was his salary  plus much more. He was before the Ark of the covenant.

Comment: I think that by "*the triangular number for 11 is 66*" you mean "the 11th triangular number is 66". And yes, "11+6=17", but where did these numbers come from, what is the point of adding them together, and why should anyone care that their sum is 17?  You seem to be saying only 10% of what you're thinking and expecting us to guess what the other 90% is.  We can't do that.

Comment: Like I said the knowledge and the wisdom of the hand of God. Didn't Moses put his hand on the head of Joshua and was filled of wisdom? I rather talk with angels, they know in fact they will say work for us.

Comment: "*[Solomon] was before the Ark of the covenant*", this at least is a straight-forward fact that anyone can understand, even if it *is* wrong (the Ark was built about 500 years before Solomon).

Comment: Guessing is what prophets do and they are right if it's not a lie.

Comment: One feature of the dimensions of the ark is that it can contain a human body (in the foetal position as many were buried prior to mechanical digging). The last word of the book of Genesis is the word for 'ark' and it refers to a coffin (to carry Joseph's bones). Thus the 'ark' should be viewed as a coffer (not as a 'seat' which is a bad translation). The death of Christ is to be seen in regard to the law (which, subsequently, was placed inside the 'coffer').

Comment: Your current reputation is 27, which is 3×9: 3 is prime, and 9 is square.
The fact that 27 can be expanded as 2+7, which is also 9, only confirms this.
Furthermore, 7+9 is 16 (a square!), and 2+9 is 11 (a prime!), and adding those two is 27, which, amazingly, is exactly what we started with.
Adding all these numbers, 2, 3, 7, 9, 11, 16, and 27, and the square 16 (which is 2×2×2×2, or 2²×2², or (2²)², and a close approximation of the golden ratio) gives 91, which is the smallest incromulent prime.
Are people aware of the important significance of this?

Comment: @Ray ButterworthNoah's Ark had measurements of 300 cubits long,50 cubits wide and a height of 30, simillar to the Ark of the covenant, which half of 5,3 and 3.

Comment: @Ray Butterworth The sun exists for counting time and every 11 years it changes cycles.

Comment: @Ray Butterworth I have counted in the book of JOB that the wealth of his livestocks were 11000 divide by 4 and 22000 after he was blessed.

Comment: In the King James version of the Bible, consider the number of times that the word "bread" occurs and the number of times the word "portion" occurs, If you divide them ( a portion of bread? "*Jesus took bread, and blessed, and brake it, and gave to them, and said, Take, eat: this is my body.*"? ), the result is 3.141592…, which is the value of pi to 99.99999% accuracy (7 nines). Now if that doesn't have important significance, then nothing in this question or its answers does. — [POPULAR BIBLE WORDS](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Popular-Bible-Words.php)

Comment: @Ray Butterworth Well the number of the hand are 3+3+3+3+2=14  which are the sides of the triangle of 5,5 and base 4, to find the angles of the triangles which can be written in three numbers 17  21 25, and 7+7+7+7+8 with sides 14+14+8=36 and it can be written  with 3 consecutive numbers  41  45  49.  7×3=21 7+3=10  21-10=11  2×8=16 2+8=10 16-10=6  11+6=17  11×6=66

Comment: I changed the title to specify a group of Christian’s from whom a definitive answer can be given.   You changed it back so I retract my reopen vote

Answer (score 6):

One feature of the dimensions of the ark is that it can contain a human body (in the foetal position as many were buried prior to mechanical digging).

The last words of the book of Genesis contain the word for 'ark' and it refers to a coffin (to carry Joseph's bones).

> ... and he was put in a coffin in Egypt. [Genesis 50:26 KJV](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/50-26.htm)

Thus the 'ark' should be viewed as a coffer (not as a 'seat' which is a bad translation).

The death of Christ is to be seen in regard to the law (which, subsequently, was placed inside the 'coffer').

> Wherefore, my brethren, ye also are become dead to the law by the body of Christ; [Romans 7:4 KJV]

---

*aron* 'ark' 195 ; 'chest' 6 ; 'coffin' 1  [Young's Analytical Concordance]

Comment: I am so confused by this question. Even more so in that I have no idea how this answer has anything to do with the body of the question. (Note that I'm not saying it's a bad answer (it *did* receive 6 votes already), only that I seem to be missing something very fundamental about the question itself.)

Comment: @RayButterworth _Does the measurement of the ark have any important significance ?_ Yes it does : the death of Christ.

Comment: Yes, I'm not dismissing your answer to the title question (in fact I just +1ed it), I'm wondering what the body of the question actually means. To me it appears to be a disjointed collection of unrelated things, with multiple unjustified conclusions popping out of nowhere. Yet it has 2 up-votes, and no one else has commented on it.  ¶ The replies to my comments on the question are a definite confirmation of [Poe's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe%27s_law#:~:text=it%20is%20utterly,article).

Comment: @RayButterworth It is true that numbers are used symbolically in scripture (2 for witness, 3 for Deity, 4 for the earth - n/s/e/w - 5 for pilgrimage, 6 for humanity, 7 for perfection and 10 for completeness). Then multiples (1,000 and 70 and 666) are also used. But the question veers off into far too much opinionated intricacy and loses its force. However the original (header) question - in my view - holds good and posits an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The golden ratio is (1+\sqrt(5))/2 = 1.618...   This ratio appears in all sorts of forms in nature.  In the spiral of a sea shell. in the number of leaves or petals in one "round" of a plant.  In the Fibonacci sequence (which models population growth).  A rectangle whose ratio of length to width is the golden ratio is considered the the most pleasing-to-the-eye ratio.  The golden ratio is even hidden in places like the ratio of a diagonal of a regular pentagon to one of its sides.  So it's an important number.  The way that pi is buried in everything round, the golden ration is buried in everything spiral.

And the ratio of the proportions of the ark is 2.5/1.5 = 1.666..., a very good approximation to the golden ratio.  Note that the end of Noah's ark was 50 by 30 cubits, and 50/30 = 1.6.

God created nature and geometry.  It's no surprise that he directed the same proportions in the Tabernacle.

Comment: Isn’t the golden ratio expressed as (a+b)/a = a/b = 1.618…? IOW **both** ratios need to have the proportion? So (1.5+1)/1.5 = 1.6667 which is close as you say. However, 1.5/1 = 1.5 is also close but does not equal (1.5+1)/1.5.

Comment: @RevelationLad  Two different approximations can be close (that's why we call them approximations) but they're still 
 different.

Answer (score 1):

Numeric symbolism of various items is speculative, but here goes.

The dimension of the Ark of the Tabernacle is given as 2.5 by 1.5 by 1.5.  The dimension of the lid of the Ark is given as 2.5 by 1.5 and no depth dimension (no thickness given).

So, what's it mean?  Here is some of the symbolism.

The circumference of the Ark top (mercy lid) is 8 (2.5+2.5+1.5+1.5).  8 is symbolic of New (8th day for example).

> And spared not the old world, but saved Noah the eighth person, a preacher of righteousness, bringing in the flood upon the world of the ungodly; 2 Peter 2:5

> And after eight days again his disciples were within, and Thomas with them: then came Jesus, the doors being shut, and stood in the midst, and said, Peace be unto you. John 20:26

Each end panel has a circumference of 6 (1.5+1.5+1.5+1.5).  6 is symbolic of man.  Two of them give us 66, but clearly not 666.

> And God saw every thing that he had made, and, behold, it was very good. And the evening and the morning were the sixth day. (Gen 1:31)

As to the Ark itself, it has a dimension of 44 (2.5+1.5+2.1+1.5=8 8*4=32 6 (end panel) *2=12 32+12=44).  44 symbolizes redemption.

> And I heard the number of them which were sealed: and there were sealed an hundred and forty and four thousand of all the tribes of the children of Israel. Rev 7:4

Moses made the Ark after the pattern.  So, in short, the symbolism would be of God redeeming man with infinite love.